# In statistics how come the normal check formula is n*p<10 and n(1-p)<10 rather than 10<n*p<n-10

Tags: statistics

I have checked that formula with a couple values assuming that p will be between 0 and 1.

I do know that it is less than or equal to however I felt it would be better to to remove it for the title.

Comment: How is this *at all* relate to linear algebra????

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Apologies. I couldn't find a tag for just algebra so I figured that "linear" was the most appropriate for this situation.

Comment: If you mean a rule of thumb to see whether you can use the normal approximation the binomial, I think you mean to have $np > 10$ and $n(1-p) > 10.$ Various authors use various rules, but $<$ makes no sense. And I think it would be confusing to try to combine the two parts of the rule.

Comment: @BruceET The two parts of this rule can be written most cleanly as $\mu \pm \sigma \in (0,n)$ which is equivalent to $n > 9\frac{1-p}{p)$ *and* $n> 9\frac{p}{1-p)$ which we can "simplify" further to get the form in Bruce's comment (strengthening the condition by replacing the coefficient $9$ with $10$ for some reason)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. Or better $\mu \pm 2.5\sigma \in (0, n).$ But all such rules are problematic. For normal aprx it helps greatly to have $p \approx .5$ so that the binom distn is nearly symmetrical. Maybe the most common rule is $\min(np, n(1-p)) > 5,$ but, denoting $q = 1-p,$ it may be better to use $\min(np/q, nq/p) > 9$ (or such). Pitman's probability book (Springer) shows it is not quite best to take normal $\mu = np,$ and $\sigma^2 = npq$ but to take skewness into account. // With today's improved software normal aprx to binomial is less often used in favor of exact binomial computation.